# Dystopian short story - greasy spoons and unhealthy food are illegal

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia

I read this at least 20 years ago, so the details are fuzzy.

What I remember is, the main character is in a greasy spoon, which is illegal. Any unhealthy food such as meat or butter is illegal. Greasy spoons are like speakeasies. The main character talks about how dangerous it is to go to one of these places, as there is no ventilation, so you end up smelling like well, a greasy spoon.

Comment: Do you recall if you read it online or in a magazine or a hardcover or paperback collection? In America, the UK, Australia, elsewhere? Is the main character a man? Does he get busted by the food police?

Comment: It was in a paperback anthology. It was American. I can't remember if he got busted.

Comment: Good, that narrows it down some. What could *really* help would be if you could recall *another* story from the same anthology. Do you recall if the anthology had any kind of theme, e.g. near-future dystopias, or was it just general science fiction, or a best-of-year anthology? Was the actual phrase "greasy spoon" used in the story?

Comment: I don't think greasy spoon was used. I could have sworn it was in an anthology with "The Tunnel Ahead" by Alice Glaser, but looking at a list of anthologies where that story was published isn't giving me any leads.

Comment: I remember a story very similar to this. Unhealthy foods were forbidden, and there were enforcers who went around on the street to check you with cameras/scanners that could detect minute amounts of unhealthy food on your teeth. Citizens were expected to smile to let the enforcers and their scanners do their job. If you weren't smiling with your teeth showing, they would say, "Smile, citizen!" And you had better smile when they told you to.

Comment: Is this related to [this question about a short story with illegal meat, "steakeasies"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260309/isaac-asimov-short-story-about-illegal-meat)?  Current most upvoted answer mentions "The Contraband Cow" by L. Sprague de Cam

Comment: @BruceWayne Only the OP can say for sure, but I don't think the Sprague de Camp story fits here. Although steakeasies are mentioned there, the protagonist never actually visits one - he makes a barbeque out in the middle of nowhere