# Isaac Asimov short story about illegal meat

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I’m trying to find a short story by Asimov that I read years ago.  The plot is that in the future, all meat is banned/illegal and carries a huge penalty if eaten/found. A few people can afford to buy it and eat it in places like opium dens.  It’s treated like heroin is today.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you read this?  A magazine or an anthology?  Why is meat banned?  Because it's unethical or because it's extremely expensive?  (The latter applies to Earth in the Elijah Bailey stories, for example.)

Comment: Are you sure about Asimov? I keep thinking The Space Merchants by Frederick Pohl....I'm fairly sure meat was banned (or maybe in the sequel)

Comment: Is it the same story asked about in [Dystopian short story - greasy spoons and unhealthy food are illegal](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/165477/dystopian-short-story-greasy-spoons-and-unhealthy-food-are-illegal)?

Comment: Not a very good match but I wonder if it could be Food of the Gods by Arthur C Clarke?

Comment: @DannyMcG in Space Merchants, people eat meat all the time, only it's low grade cultured meat ("Chicken Little"), not something from live animals (which is not banned, just unavailable for most people).

Comment: This is not the anwser to the question, but there was a question a while ago about a similar story by Arthur C. Clarke, who is sometimes confused with Asimov, set in an Senate hearing in a future where all food is synthiczed and nobody eats plants or animals anymore.

Comment: @M.A.Golding That's "The Food of the Gods", referenced earlier by skyjack

Comment: [Number Ten Q Street](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?98725) by Helen McCloy is about a woman who goes to a secret bar to eat unhealthy food. In the end she gets caught and is sentenced to being frozen (some kind of suspended animation) for the rest of her life. Does this ring a bell? Steak is mentioned as one of the forbidden unhealthy foods, though the woman eats bread and butter not a steak.

Comment: @JohnRennie The McCloy story could also fit the "greasy spoon" question, there was a remark about the policeman sniffing the smell of bread

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez I did wonder about that, but the other question specifically says it was a man, not a woman, in the greasy spoon, and also that there was a comment about "no ventilation" that isn't in McCloy's story.

Comment: Hi all.  Thanks do much for your replies.  I guess my Memory is not what is was - it looks like it wasn’t Asimov.  The only author that it could be from  you replies is Arthur C Clark.  So I found and bought that.  We shall see!

Comment: @Stu So definitely not "The Contraband Cow" then?

Comment: I don’t recall having read  that author

Comment: No-one has suggested _[Make Room, Make Room!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_Room!_Make_Room!)_ by Harry Harrison, which was made into the movie _Soylent Green_. Meat can only be bought on the black market.  (Despite the movie's final shocker (which IIRC wasn't in the book), recall it's advertised as being "made from seaweed".)

Comment: Yes, I saw Soylent Green.  Not read the book, but the film is not what I read.  Totally different emphasis.  Thanks, though!  My book  (ACClarke) arrives this week, and I’m hopeful.

Comment: It doesn't sound like an Asimov story.

Answer (score 43):

I'll suggest "[The Contraband Cow](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46574)" by L. Sprague de Camp, first published in [*Astounding* in 1942](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v29n05_1942-07_dtsg0318/page/n37/mode/2up). Although it is not actually by Asimov as specified in the question, Sprague de Camp was a contemporary and a friend of his, which could lead to their work being confused.

It is set in a future USA, forming part of the "Federation of Democratic and Libertarian States". A Hindu majority in the Federation has forced through a law banning the consumption of "all animals of the subfamily Bovinae of the family Bovidae, the same comprising kine, buffaloes, bison, zebus, gayals, bantengs, yaks, and species closely related thereto", which mainly affects Americans wanting to eat steaks or roast beef. As far as I can see the penalties for being caught are not given, but I suppose they are reasonably grave.

Beef is available illegally from "steakeasies", and is produced either by local steakleggers (who are no problem to anyone), or on a larger scale by Mexican cartels. The parallels to illegal alcohol under Prohibition are very clear. Two researchers who are developing synthetic meat go to a secluded area to eat a steak, but one of them is first arrested by a Sikh Federal agent, and then kidnapped by a Mexican cartel who wish to shut down this competition to their trade. Various twist and turns of plot then

> lead to the father of the Federal patrolman, an eminent Indian politician, overturning the anti-vacacide law, thereby assuring ruin for the cartels.